# Do we need to deallocate CFArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `CFMutableArray` that I created using `CFArrayCreateMutable`.
I just need to know whether I need to deallocate this array by myself, or is it already taken care by the ARC? If I need to deallocate this, how can I, since I didn't find any function like `CFArrayRelease`?

Comment: Yes you need to deallocate ARC is not going to manage core foundation objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Core Foundation objects that were allocated/copied/retained by user should be released by the user. To release the CFMutableArray, you use CFRelease() function.

```
CFMutableArrayRef ar = CFArrayCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, capacity, NULL);
// some code
CFRelease(ar);
```

More information here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-CJBEJBHH

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Articles/lifecycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002439-SW1

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we need.

You have two options:

Transfer ownership to ARC while creating the item by casting the type to an Objective-C object.

```
NSMutableArray *array = (NSMutableArray *)CFBridgingRelease(CFArrayCreateMutable … )
```

Or release the object later

```
CFRelease(cfMutableArray)
```

Comment: Or: NSMutableArray *array = (__bridge NSMutableArray *)CFArrayCreateMutable(…);